# how to underline text with different color in WP8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following code:

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="65">
       <Underline Foreground="DeepSkyBlue">
            <Run Foreground="Turquoise" Text="{Binding SomeProp}"></Run>
       </Underline>
 </TextBlock>
```

What I need is to paint in turquoise color my text and underline it using other color - "DeepSkyBlue". I thought `Run` element should overwrite the parent control `Foreground` property for itself but it looks like it was wrong assumption (actually it overwrites but I need underline to stay other color). Is it possible in WP8? If yes, what is wrong with my sample?

**EDIT:** with the help of the [Pantelis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028868/pantelis) and [aloisdg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248177/aloisdg) the working code looks like this:

```
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="65">
                    <Run Foreground="Turquoise" Text="{Binding SomeProp}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Without being 100% sure, I don't think that this is possible.
You could use a stackpanel to represent the textblock and use a rectangle or border or any other element that would suit the case to draw the underline.

Comment: Your answer was correct. Using your approach with Border + Grid solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way to do it, but you can use a [`border`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<Border BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
    <!-- your text -->
</Border>
```

Answer (score -1):

For these purposes I use TextDecorations property.
For example in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="undelinedTextBlock" 
           TextDecorations="Underline"
           Text="Underlined text"/>
```

In C#:

```
 undelinedTextBlock.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
```

See details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textdecorations(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Note that solution fits to wp8.1 silverlight too