# LinearGradiantBrush applied on the underline and the text separately but not together

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I was trying to answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664044/how-to-underline-text-with-different-color-in-wp8) yesterday, the guy tried to color the text in a TextBlock with a color and the underline with another color, it was apparently not possible.

I tried to play the smarty, and wanted to apply a `LinearGradiantBrush` so I can force the underline with a color and a text with another doing this :

```
<TextBlock Margin="68,232,124,300" FontSize="35">
       <Underline>
           <Underline.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                     <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.764"/>
                     <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.773"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Underline.Foreground>
           Here s my text
       </Underline>
</TextBlock>
```

[image: LinearGradiantBrush not applied on all the object as one]

As you can see the GradiantBrush is applied separately, Weird, but why ?

I expected it to be graduant from white to red from the extra bottom to the extra top (including the line all as one object), not like it's shown here.

Is that normal ?? is it supposed to be like that?

**Update :**

This behavior exists in WPF as well.

Comment: FWIW, screenshots of code make it harder for others to test the code, because they need to type it all, instead of paste into test application.  Plus the question gets less exposure to the search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the color of the underline in WPF.

**WPF XAML**

```
<TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground='Red'
           Text='Here is my text'>
  <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
    <TextDecoration>
      <TextDecoration.Pen>
        <Pen Brush='Orange' />
      </TextDecoration.Pen>
    </TextDecoration>
  </TextBlock.TextDecorations>

</TextBlock>
```

[image]

This doesn't seem possible in  the Windows Phone and Silverlight implementation.

One possiblility is to use a typeface with a built-in underline.

[Example of Underline typeface](http://www.eaglefonts.com/labtop-underline-ttf-140061.htm)

In that case, a gradient might work, because the underline is part of the word.

Answer (score 2):

TextDecorations in Windows Phone are little limited - Windows Phone inherited Silverlight functionality so that [only Underline is available.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textdecorations%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Additional to that, it seems that `TextBlock.Foreground` and `Underline.Foreground` are bound to each other (or are the same property?). TextDecoration is an additional element and thus Brush is applied separately (correct me if I'm wrong).

Because of those limitations we aren't able to do [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations.underline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm nor sure, but how can you be sure that TextDecoration is an additional element ? the TextBlock style is even empty, it's a whole united Element I guess, or am i wrong ?

Comment: @AymenDaoudi I'ce failed to find documentation about that. It's my suspicion as Underline is an object in TextDecorations Collection.

Comment: Well as you can see I didn't use a TextDecoration, I used an Underline  which is an inline, an inline itself has TextDecorations as a property, so I deduce they are not the same, you see what I mean ?

Comment: @AymenDaoudi I think they are the same (thought it's my next suspicition). Probably Underline constructor adds TextDecoration.Underline to TextDecorations Collections. For me it isn't also clear. I see your point and agree that it's little weird. To many suspictions - I will delete my answer and see what other say.

Comment: No it's ok don't delete it, let's just wait and see